# Is there way I can merge all grease pencil keyframes into one frame？

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d

Is there way I can merge all grease pencil keyframes into one frame？So I've seen there is multiframe
option in blender, but it doesn't allow me to copy though, wonder if there is way I can merge all the keyframes drawings into one drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste in *Edit Mode*.

Also you can merge layers in the dropdown menu near layers *Merge Down*, though there is an issue if the keyframes don't match up

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)